# Combination of Specific special character causes Error

Tags: java, android, json

When I am sending a TextEdit data as a JSON with data as a combination of  `";` the app fails every time.
In detail if I am entering my username as anything but password as `";` the resultant JSON file looks like:-

```
{"UserName":"qa@1.com","Password":"\";"}
```

I have searched a lot, what I could understand is the resultant JSON data voilates the syntax which results in throwing Default exception. I tried to get rid of special symbol by using `URLEncoder.encode()` method. But now the problem is in decoding.
Any help at any step will be very grateful.

Logcat:

```
I/SW_HttpClient(448): sending post: {"UserName":"qa@1.com","Password":"\";"}
I/SW_HttpClient(448): HTTPResponse received in [2326ms]
I/SW_HttpClient(448): stream returned: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ---- AN HTML PAGE.... A DEFAULT HANDLER>
```

Comment: "the app fails" doesn't give us much information. What *exactly* happens, where, using what code?

Comment: if fails then you have a good news in form of Logcat share it here

Comment: Exactly-- it is throwing Uncaught exception which is handled by my default Exception handler.

Comment: The problem occures only when my password field contains double-quotes followed by semicolon. For double quotes an escape character is inserted automatically but i have heard that java dont have any escape character for semicolon.

Comment: so JSON builder gives problem or when you pass this to HTTP at that time problem starts?

Comment: This is [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) - post the problem encode and decode code and any stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the following code

```
String EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI = Utils.authenticate+"?UserName="+uid+"&Email="+eid+"&Password="+URLEncoder.encode(pwd,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Sorry but i had already mentioned that I already tried URLEncoder.encode() method.It converts "; to %22%3B, I don't know how to decode that.

Comment: I really don't see how this Answer is relevant.  The problem is about JSON not URLs

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided in the Question is valid.

The JSON spec **requires** double quotes in strings to be escaped with a backslash.  Read the syntax graphs here - http://www.json.org/.

If something is throwing an exception while parsing that JSON, then either the parser is buggy or the exception means something else.

---

> I have searched a lot, what I could understand is the resultant JSON data voilates the syntax

Your understanding is incorrect.

> I tried to get rid of special symbol by using URLEncoder.encode() method.

That is a mistake, and is only going to make matters worse:

1. The backslash SHOULD be there.
2. The server or whatever that processes the JSON will NOT be expecting random escaping from a completely different standard.

> But now the problem is in decoding.

Exactly.

Comment: Backslash is not an escape character for semicolon... not in java atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Following provided JSON can be parsed through GSON library with below code

```
private String sampledata = "{\"UserName\":\"qa@1.com\",\"Password\":\"\\\";\"}";

Gson g = new Gson();
g.fromJson(sampledata, sample.class);



public class sample {

    public String UserName;
    public String Password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For decoding the text I got the solution with..

```
 URLDecoder.decode(String, String);
```